# Quitar el fondo blanco de mi imagen png

Tags: android, android-studio, imagen

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación en Android Studio y he leído en varios hilos que para quitar el fondo en mi `buttonimage` tengo que poner en sus propiedades Android: `Background="null"`.

Efectivamente se me quita el fondo y queda una imagen transparente que es lo que busco, pero me salta el siguiente error:

> Error:(14, 28) String types not allowed (at 'background' with value
>   '').

¿Alguien me puede decir como resolverlo?

Comment: Puedes probar con `android:background="@null"`?

Comment: Lo cabo de probar y funciona correctamente ! Gracias :D

Comment: En ese caso, acepta la respuesta de @Reductor ya que es correcta. Me alegro de que te haya funcionado

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente en la actividad correspondiente:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.id_de_tu_imageView);

image.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

o como ha dicho el compañero "Pikoh"  `android:background="@null"`en el ImageView de tu xml.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza el simbolo '@' delante de null al establecer la referencia; de esta manera:
`android:background="@null"`, también puedes utilizar `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`.

Tu error se debe a que estas asignando un string a la propiedad background cuando esta necesita una referencia a un drawable, en este caso @null representa la ausencia de este.

Cuando le asignas la referencia @null a la propiedad background, se mostrará cualquier elemento que se encuentre detrás, en tu caso especifico, desaparecerá el fondo y los bordes del botón.

Comment: Hola W. Reyes. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Intenta explicar un poco más la respuesta para que se entienda mejor el funcionamiento de las propiedades. Mira [answer] para mejorarla. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Si defines la propiedad [**android:background**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:background), es estrictamente necesario definas el recurso, puede se color, imagen o un drawable .xml, el color puede incluso tener transparencia

```
android:background="@???/???"
```

Por el mensaje de error deduzco que cargas un valor vacio:

```
android:background=""
```

o el recurso hace referencia a un valor vacio, por ejemplo :

```
android:background="@color/mi_color"
```

donde el valor no ha sido especificado:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="mi_color"></color> 
</resources>
```

---

> ¿Como quitar el fondo blanco de mi **ImageButton**'?

Programaticamente pueds asignar un valor null al fondo:

```
imageButton.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

o mediante la definición del valor en el layout:

```
android:background="@null"
```